# Interpret results Regression

Tags: python, plot, regression

I made an ordinal regression model (first time performing regression, be merciful) and now I need to evaluate it. What would be the best way? (I use `mord` API for the ordinal regression)

These are the tasks I am trying to complete:

> 3) Build a regression model that will predict the rating score of each
>   product based on attributes which correspond to some very common words
>   used in the reviews (selection of how many words is left to you as a
>   decision). So, for each product you will have a long(ish) vector of
>   attributes based on how many times each word appears in reviews of
>   this product. Your target variable is the rating. You will be judged
>   on the process of building the model (regularization, subset
>   selection, validation set, etc.) and not so much on the accuracy of
>   the results.
>
> 4) Having the vectors from Question 3, perform
>   dimensionality reduction (either PCA or NMF). Can you conclude how
>   many components you can keep? Experiment with this parameter and
>   justify your final conclusion.

This is my code for it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import textblob
import nltk
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from textblob import Word
from collections import Counter
import seaborn as sns
import mord as m
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

%matplotlib inline

df = # import dataframe from link

#Clean up Rating (whilst doing 'hand cleaning' I saw data outside of the [0,5] range; needs to be corrected; this could have been spotted by plotting the data on histogram but since I saw this while going throught the data I feel plotting it is an unnecessary step)
df.loc[df.Rating > 5, 'Rating'] = np.NaN
df.loc[df.Rating < 1, 'Rating'] = np.NaN

# Convert weights to same measure (pounds). Most of the weights I inspected seem wrong...

for i in range(0, df.weight.size-1):
    cell = df.weight[i]
    while (cell == 0 and i < df.weight.size-1):
        i += 1
        cell = df.weight[i]
    if not(isinstance(cell, float)) and  not(isinstance(cell, int)):
            number = ''.join([x for x in cell if (x.isdigit() or x=='.')])
            num = float(number)
            if bool(re.search('ounces', cell)):
                df.loc[i, 'weight'] = num * 0.0625    # Ounces to pounds conversion
            else:
                df.loc[i, 'weight'] = num            # Introduce only number (without measure type)

df.loc[:, "Review"] = df["Title"] + str(' - ') + df["Text"]
df.drop('Title', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Text', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Brand', 'Name', 'NumsHelpful', 'Rating', 'Weight(Pounds)', 'Review']
df['Weight(Pounds)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Weight(Pounds)'], errors='coerce')
df['Brand'] = df['Brand'].astype(str)
df['Review'] = df['Review'].astype(str)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(str)

d = {'Brand':'first', 
     'NumsHelpful':'mean', 
     'Rating':'mean',
     'Weight(Pounds)':'first',
     'Review':'/'.join, 
    }
df = df.groupby('Name').agg(d).reset_index()

df.Rating = df.Rating.round()
df.NumsHelpful = df.NumsHelpful.round()

df['Review2'] = df['Review'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))

df['Review2'] = df['Review2'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')

stop = stopwords.words('english')
df['Review2'] = df['Review2'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))

freq = pd.Series(' '.join(df['Review2']).split()).value_counts()[:20]

common = ['wine', 'mix', 'taste', 'drink', 'one', 'price', 'product', 'flavour', 'would', 'bitters', 'bottle', 'buy','really', 'make']
df['Review2'] = df['Review2'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in common))

freq = pd.Series(' '.join(df['Review2']).split()).value_counts()[-10:]

freq = list(freq.index)
df['Review2'] = df['Review2'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in freq))

df['words'] = df.Review2.str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')

df['Review2'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize('v') for word in x]))

df['Review2'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
# Create word matrix
bow = df.Review2.str.split().apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
rating = df['Rating']
df_rating = pd.DataFrame([rating])
df_rating = df_rating.transpose()
bow = bow.join(df_rating)

# Remove some columns and rows
bow = bow.loc[(bow['Rating'].notna()), ~(bow.sum(0) < 80)]

# Divide into train - validation - test
bow.fillna(0, inplace=True)
rating = bow['Rating']
bow = bow.drop('Rating', 1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(bow, rating, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

# Run regression
regr = m.OrdinalRidge()
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
scores = cross_val_score(regr, bow, rating, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
# scores -> array([0.75438596, 0.73684211, 0.66071429, 0.53571429, 0.60714286])
# avg_score -> Accuracy: 0.66 (+/- 0.16)

# Do PCA (dimensionality reduction)
scaler = StandardScaler()
# Fit on training set only.
scaler.fit(x_train)
# Apply transform to both the training set and the test set.
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
# Make an instance of the Model
pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(x_train)
x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
x_test = pca.transform(x_test)
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
scores = cross_val_score(regr, bow, rating, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

What are your thoughts on the above code?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLvyyZVr_wriSVBUCg-htZNPbszQlAPkCDxz64nza7o/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to the dataset

[This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P4I9YEGxh2NYggvCTOj5c6mpC7YuCr4nUKAwrer9IEw/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a google.doc containing the source code (Python)

Comment: I could not run your code without import statements or data. If you sort the data before plotting, the line plot will go from low to high values without zig-zag.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I have updated the code to the latest version and put in a link to the dataset + imports. Any constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I spliced together the two pieces of code, and now get the error "NameError: name 'df' is not defined".

Comment: @JamesPhillips I am the worst... sorry. I added all the code in the question. Moreover if you look in the `edit` you will see a link to the original dataset (the previous link I had was to an already altered version) and a link to a google doc containing a transcript of my jupyter notebook which contains comments about the procedure. Sorry again for the failed attempt and thank you for your time!